# Query Optimization - 10001

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I need help with optimizing this particular query. If you see there are multiple sub-queries running but they are running on the same table. The problem is that GROUP BY is used by 2 sub-queries and there are 2 other sub-queries that don't use GROUP BY. Can these 4 sub-queries be combined to just scan the table once.

```
WITH f AS
(
  SELECT a.custom_referal_page,
     a.campaign_id,
     a.domain_user_id,
     a.event_name,
     COUNT(a.event_name),
     (SELECT COUNT(a1.event_name)
      FROM action_fact_new_wodim a1
      WHERE a1.domain_url = 'alternativeapparel.com'
      AND   a1.event_name = 'AltOrig PerfCapSl GoToPro'
     -- AND   a1.date_stamp BETWEEN '20140501' AND '20140530'          
     AND   a1.time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-05-01 14:43:15' AND '2014-05-30 14:43:15'
      AND   event_name != 'Page load'
      AND   event_name != 'Page unload') AS totalCount,
     (SELECT COUNT(domain_user_id)
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a1.domain_user_id,
                   a1.custom_referal_page
            FROM action_fact_new_wodim a1
            WHERE a1.domain_url = 'alternativeapparel.com'
            AND   a1.event_name = 'AltOrig PerfCapSl GoToPro'
      --            AND   a1.date_stamp BETWEEN '20140501' AND '20140530'          
           AND   a1.time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-05-01 14:43:15' AND '2014-05-30 14:43:15'
            AND   event_name != 'Page load'
            AND   event_name != 'Page unload') AS a2) AS uniqueCount,
     (SELECT COUNT(domain_user_id)
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT domain_user_id
            FROM action_fact_new_wodim a1
            WHERE a1.domain_url = 'alternativeapparel.com'
            AND   a1.event_name = 'AltOrig PerfCapSl GoToPro'
       --     AND   a1.date_stamp BETWEEN '20140501' AND '20140530'          
            AND   a1.time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-05-01 14:43:15' AND '2014-05-30 14:43:15'
            AND   event_name != 'Page load'
            AND   event_name != 'Page unload') AS a2) AS totalUniqueCount
FROM action_fact_new_wodim a
WHERE a.domain_url = 'alternativeapparel.com'
AND   a.event_name = 'AltOrig PerfCapSl GoToPro'
-- AND   a.date_stamp BETWEEN '20140501' AND '20140530'          
AND   a.time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-05-01 14:43:15' AND '2014-05-30 14:43:15'
AND   event_name != 'Page load'
AND   event_name != 'Page unload'
GROUP BY a.custom_referal_page,
       a.campaign_id,
       a.domain_user_id,
       a.event_name
)

SELECT custom_referal_page,
    campaign_id,
    SUM(COUNT) AS COUNT,
    MAX(totalCount) AS totalCount,
    COUNT(uniqueCount) AS uniqueCount,
    MAX(totalUniqueCount) AS totalUniqueCount
FROM f
GROUP BY custom_referal_page,
    campaign_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Output:
    custom_referal_page       campaign_id   count   totalcount  uniquecount totaluniquecount
    https://www.google.ca/    null          10838   20153       5346        9906
    https://www.google.com/   null          3040    20153       1727        9906

Comment: Each of your where clauses have a specific event and then != the page load / unload which makes is pointless as it can only be one or the other.  Also, do you intend to base query on time_stamp or date_stamp (which is commented out)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite crazy, and maybe by stepping back this option might work for you.  All your conditions were the same, you were just getting different counts.  You SHOULD be able to get distinct counts and total counts passing through the table once with the group by such as...

```
select
      a1.custom_referal_page,
      a1.campaign_id,
      COUNT(*) as TotalEvents,
      COUNT( distinct a1.event_name ) as CntDistEvents,
      COUNT( distinct a1.domain_user_id + a1.custom_referal_page ) as CntDistDomRef,
      COUNT( distinct a1.domain_user_id ) as CntDistUsers
   FROM 
      action_fact_new_wodim a1
   WHERE 
          a1.domain_url = 'alternativeapparel.com'
      AND a1.event_name = 'AltOrig PerfCapSl GoToPro'
      AND a1.time_stamp BETWEEN '2014-05-01 14:43:15' AND '2014-05-30 14:43:15'
   group by
      a1.custom_referal_page,
      a1.campaign_id
```

That said, I would have an index on your table on ( domain_url, event_name, time_Stamp ), but if you are actually going to query on the date_stamp, then adjust the index and where clause.

Look at the numbers this provides you for the distinct references and add the order by based on whichever makes sense...